# Pygame sprites group

Tags: python, pygame

While developing my game I came across slight problem with group of sprites. What I am trying to do is to be able to detect collision of the character(dog) with sprite(bone) and when that collision occurs, add points and change coordinates on the screen. At this stage, I am able to add points and place the bone in different location on the screen but the first instance of the bone stays in the same spot. How can I remove my sprite from one place of the screen to another?

My code:

```
sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
sprites_no = 20
```

...

```
class MySprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.health = 3
        self.name = name
        self.points = 0

    def printName(self):
        print (self.name)


class Dog(MySprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, name):
        super(Dog, self).__init__(name)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("dog_left.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
        self.move_x = 0
        self.move_y = 0



    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def takeBone(self):
        takebone = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, sprites, True)
        if takebone == True:
            self.points += 1
            bone.changePos()
```

...

```
class Bone(MySprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, name):
        super(Bone, self).__init__(name)
        self.name = name
        self.image = pygame.image.load("bone.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
```

...

```
for i in range(sprites_no):
    sp1_x = random.randrange(0, 475)
    sp1_y = random.randrange(0, 275)
    sp1 = Bone([sp1_x, sp1_y],"Bone")
    sprites.append(sp1)
```

The error I am getting at the moment is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\game\new.py", line 86, in 
    sprites.append(sp1)
AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'append'

Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `pygame.sprite.Group` is not the same as a list; you cannot `append` to it. Instead, per [the documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group), you should `add` to it:

```
sprites.add(sp1)
```

Comment: I have tried that but then another error comes up: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\game\new.py", line 86, in <module>
    sprites.add(sp1)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 360, in add
    sprite.add_internal(self)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 163, in add_internal
    self.__g[group] = 0
AttributeError: 'Bone' object has no attribute '_Sprite__g'

Comment: Just realized what am I doing, I apologize, and thanks for help